# NSRunLoop API difference

Tags: ios, nsrunloop

NSRunLoop has two apis:

```
- (BOOL)runMode:(NSString *)mode beforeDate:(NSDate *)limitDate
```

and

```
- (void)acceptInputForMode:(NSString *)mode beforeDate:(NSDate *)limitDate
```

I mean they are same except return value, or there are other differences?

Comment: By API you mean method, right? Or is this some new meaning of API that I haven't come across before?

Comment: Hmmm, I thought they differ in timer handling, but reading the documentation closely I cannot spot a difference either.

Answer (score 5):

As @DarkDust hints at, it used to have to do with timers. See [Chris Kane's discussions on the Cocoa mailing list](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/81770-nsrunloop-looping-more-than-once.html). At one point, `runMode:beforeDate:` was a wrapper around `limitDateForMode:` and `acceptInputForMode:beforeDate:` (since `acceptInputForMode:beforeDate:` didn't fire timers). My reading of the docs, headers, and crash stacks suggests that today, they behave identically (calling `CFRunLoopRunInMode()`, which does fire timers). But I haven't built a test app to confirm.

If you read the original [NeXT ObjC manual](http://objc.toodarkpark.net/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRunLoop/acceptInputForMode%3abeforeDate%3a), `acceptInputForMode:beforeDate:` used to explicitly not fire timers:

> Blocks awaiting input from the ports in the port list for the input mode mode until the time specified by limitDate. Use the limitDateForMode: method to calculate limitDate. If input arrives, it is processed using the NSPort delegates. This method does not check the timers associated with mode, thus it does not fire timers even if their scheduled fire dates have passed.

Timers were explicitly handled as a side effect of `limitDateForMode:`

> Polls mode's input sources for their limit date (if any) and returns the earliest limit date for this mode. Uses the NSPort delegate method limitDateForMode: to determine the limit dates of ports. Fires timers if their limit dates have passed. Polls ports for activities appropriate for mode. Returns nil if there are no input sources for this mode.

Which is why `runMode:beforeDate:` was added as a convenience (see `NSRunloop.h`):

```
@interface NSRunLoop (NSRunLoopConveniences)

- (void)run; 
- (void)runUntilDate:(NSDate *)limitDate;
- (BOOL)runMode:(NSString *)mode beforeDate:(NSDate *)limitDate;

#if (TARGET_OS_MAC && !(TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE))
- (void)configureAsServer NS_DEPRECATED(10_0, 10_5, 2_0, 2_0);
#endif
```

See also from NeXT:

> The method limitDateForMode: returns the earliest limit date of all the input sources for the mode NSDefaultRunLoopMode. acceptInputForMode:beforeDate: runs the loop until that date, processing any input it receives until that time. As a convenience, you can use runMode:beforeDate: instead. It invokes acceptInputForMode:beforeDate: and limitDateForMode: with the mode you supply.

So the short answer: history.

Comment: +1 Great, thorough answer. Glad to have the link to the NeXT docs, too.

Comment: Cool... details answer for new usage info. As my testing does not expose more difference so far.